# Recovery Old Password of Deployment in IntelliJ12

Tags: intellij-idea

I need a help with a problem.

I have a old ftp account in the deployment of IntelliJ12. How I recover it? I mean how I recover the password?

(Sorry for my strange english)

Comment: You want to retrieve a password to an FTP server that IntelliJ has saved?

Comment: No answer? Id like to know this too - since I know my main password which is used to encrypt FTP passwords I should be able to safely recover it with that password right?

Answer (score -2):

IDEA lists your license-key if you from the menu go Help > Register...

otherwise get in touch with your Jetbrains support:

http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/new